# How do I recompile an assembly targeting the MonoTouch profile?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

On http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/assemblies it says that if I want to provide my code as an assembly to other MonoTouch developers: "You must recompile your source code to generate assemblies targeting the MonoTouch profile".

How do I do that?

How do I do that with Visual Studio?

How do I do that with msbuild?

I found MonoDevAssist at http://monodevassist.codeplex.com/documentation, but the instruction there said I should copy a bunch of DLLs from "your Mac". I don't have a Mac. I have installed MonoTouch for Android on my Windows machine, but I can't find a directory like the one in that description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have installed MonoTouch for Android on my Windows machine

What you likely have is **Mono for Android** which runs fine on Windows and targets Android.

**MonoTouch** is another product from Xamarin, targeting iOS (iPhones, iPod, iPads) and it requires a Mac computer.

Even if there's quite a bit of features shared between the two products, in general, you need to look at the documentation for the product you have.

> How do I do that?

Simply re-compile your existing source code including reference(s) to the assemblies that are shipped with Mono for Android.

> How do I do that with Visual Studio?

Create a new project, e.g. a library, for Mono for Android. Add your source code to the project. Add references to the SDK assemblies you requires. Rebuild your code.